# How to display ZIP codes in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Boston has leading zeros for its ZIP codes.

Google Sheets is very helpful in removing leading zeros but unfortunately it removes them from Boston ZIP codes.

I tried to find a number format for address ZIP codes but couldn't find one. I also tried to find a number format that preserves leading zeros but couldn't figure it out.

How can I prevent Google Sheets from removing the leading zero in ZIP codes?

[image: Google search of Boston ZIP codes]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Select the range to apply the Zip code format
2. Go to Format > Number > More Formats > Custom number format...

[image: Custom number format]

3. Write `00000` in the entry box.
4. Click the the **Apply** button.

Answer (score 3):

You can also just put an apostrophe in front of the zip codes like

```
'02108
```

Or select the column / cells that will contain the zip codes and set to the following as listed above

```
Format -> Number -> Plain Text
```

Answer (score 2):

Format>Number>Plain Text works great to allow leading zeros.

To restore the leading zeros if they are gone without having to add them manually, [I found this article](http://judisohn.com/2011/06/26/tip-how-to-add-leading-zero-for-zip-codes-in/).

Basically you can use a formula to check the length of your zip code column. If the length is 4, it adds a leading 0.

The formula (assuming your zip code is in column B):

```
=if(len(B2)=4,"0"&B2,B2)
```

Make sure to format the resulting column as plain text as well.

[image]

Comment: While the method in the referred page works several parts of that page are obsolete. See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/90982/88163 for the method that the referred page says that it's not avaible for the Google spreadsheets.