# Assigning ID automatically using Arrayformula and text

Tags: google-sheets

I'm probably approaching this wrong but I'm trying to automatically assign an ID to an item, I'd like the format to be C#### where #### starts with 0s and is assigned as 0001.

The expected output would be C0001, C0002, C0003... C9999

`={"UID"; ARRAYFORMULA(if(D2:D="", "", ("C"&(text(row(D2:D)-1), "####"))))}`

Without the text formatting, it has no issues assigning the first item as C1. If I assign the preceding 0's, it would generate as C0001... C00011 as opposed to C0011.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `"####"` use `"0000"`

Related

- [How to display ZIP codes in Google Sheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/90967/88163)

Comment: "0000" worked. Thanks!